# Scraping: recover gleif informations from pandas

Tags: python

I have a database in it, and I want to fill in the LEIs in GLEIF https://www.gleif.org/fr/about/ and retrieve the information. I used pygleif and leipy, but it doesn't work.

My code:

```
for leipy import GLEIF

gleif = GLEIF(api_version='v1')
raw_output, results, results_df = gleif.request(['HWUPKR0MPOU8FGXBT394'], return_dataframe=True)

Error connecting to host!

from pygleif import GLEIF

data = GLEIF('8RS0AKOLN987042F2V04')
print(data.registration.initial_registration_date)

URLError: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 502 badgateway>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the latest pygleif version from the GitHub repository. The version that is available via pip is outdated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).